# Why do SWRL rules change my class hierarchy?

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, swrl

I'm building a mid-size ontology with only 5 SWRL rules. Every time I run my SWRL rules and try to transfer the inferred axioms to the ontology, my class hierarchy gets changed a lot. Subclasses become sibling classes to what were previously their superclasses, even though when I check the info tab, theyre still marked as subclasses properly.

On the 'Inferred' tab of the class hierarchy, things stay in order, but the asserted tab gets really messy.

Further, my SWRL rules are only ~50% effective; many individuals which satisfy the antecedent dont seem to be affected by running the rules. I went through each of these individuals, and I cant seem to find anything in common that would be making things go wrong.

I've tried a few different reasoners, but ELK seems to be the only one which can reason through the ontology in less than a minute (Pellet was taking around 10). But every reasoner had the same issue.

I'm also using protege 5.6.1

Comment: ELK is just an OWL EL reasoner, it doesn't do anythng with SWRL rules during inference. Other than that, without seeing the rules it's hard to judge. Moreover, I don't get the point with *"my class hierarchy gets changed"* - I mean, you add inferred axioms to the ontology, which means you make those axioms explicit an asserted. Of course this could change a class hierarchy - or do I misunderstand your point?

Comment: *"Further, my SWRL rules are only ~50% effective"* - nobody here can help you without the ontology/data - that is the main problem here. Neither do we know the rules nor the instance data nor the individuals where you think the SWRL inference "missed" something on

Comment: Apologies, this could have been phrased better. The class hierarchy is changed in ways that have no mentions in any of my swrl rules (although maybe a rule with a mistake has very far reaching consequences). Many classes retain the correct 'subclass of' values, but visually, in protege, all classes move to become sibling classes. It might be better to say that the class hierarchy itself doesnt change, but protege seems to think it does.

Comment: A rule that seems to be not firing is this: Project(?p) ^ StartYear(?p, ?sy) ^ EndYear(?p, ?ey) ^ swrlb:subtract(?d, ?ey, ?sy) ^ swrlb:add(?cd, 1, ?d) -> Duration(?p, ?d)

Comment: And each individual in the 'project' class is marked with a start year and end year data in xsd:decimal, but only around half get marked with the 'duration'